# How to print line numbers?

Tags: c, line-numbers

I'm new to programming and I have a program which runs but I need to display line numbers for it. Could I used the C macro `__LINE__`? If so where could I insert it in the code and if not what could I do in order for the program to print out line numbers along with the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `__LINE__` macro expands into an integral line number (the presumed line number within the source file) so you can pretty well use it anywhere an integer is usable:

```
printf ("This line is %d.\n", __LINE__);
```

From `C11 6.10.8.1 Mandatory macros`:

> `__LINE__` The presumed line number (within the current source file) of the current source line (an integer constant).

---

If, as may be the case based on your comments, you need simply have a program that outputs itself with line numbers, I'd suggest *not* using `__LINE__` for that.

Instead, it would probably be better to have the program keep a record of which line it's on, and output that before the line itself. See, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    static char buff[100000];
    int lineNum = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen (__FILE__, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        while (fgets (buff, sizeof (buff), fp) != NULL) {
            printf ("%7d: %s", ++lineNum, buff);
        }
        fclose (fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb but would I need to insert that once into the code or right before each line?

Comment: @mishi, you would need to insert it everywhere you wanted the line number printed out. Doing it before every line of code would be a fair bit of work so you may need to step back and tell us the actual problem you're trying to solve. It's likely there's a better way.

Comment: i made a program that reads its own source file and now i need to open another text file with the same source file but include line numbers in the text file

Comment: @mishi, in that case, I'd simply modify the program to keep a count of what line it's on and output that before the line itself. That's going to be a lot easier than trying to use `__LINE__`.